# AWS IAM to allow access to certain website path/folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to use AWS IAM to create users, roles and policies that can restrict access to certain website/web application's folders/path?

Let's say I have the following scenario:

In IAM, we got 5 users, 3 belong to authorized group called webAdmin and 2 belong to signedUpUser group.

We got a Windows server 2012, a simple .NET web application hosted on IIS.
The web application have 2 folders, 1 called /admin and the other called /user-profile

Can IAM allow both group of users to access the folder /user-profile
and allow only user belong to group webAdmin to access to webAdmin folder?

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

IAM is for managing access to the AWS API for various AWS services only and cannot be used to restrict certain users access to a web server or any other service running on an EC2 instance (I assume that's what you mean here).

You will have to provide your own authentication/authorization scheme that is compatible with .NET/IIS.